Finding out different phases and microstructures within an interface, of joined components
I had a query regarding identifying phases and other components formed within the joined interface. I have read some papers from the SEM analysis, but the procedure for how they will finally analyze the results is not mentioned. Please don't be too harsh on me.

The classic method is to cut a cross-section of the joint, polish it to optical flatness, and apply a grain boundary etch- then photograph the developed microstructure in a metallographic microscope or wafer inspection microscope at 50x to 100x power.
Different grain boundary etches exist for different alloy systems (iron, copper, aluminum, magnesium, titanium, etc.)
A handbook of materials science specializing in metallography will furnish you all the details.
